# Groovy Redis plugin timeout issue

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, redis, weblogic

Using Redis plugin 1.0.0 on Grails 2.0.4 on WebLogic 11 with JRockit (we also tested on Tomcat 7), we're updating Redis using the following but keep getting a timeout exception...

```
template.execute(new RedisCallback<Object>() {
   public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
      connection.multi()    
      for( def cacheUpdate : cacheList)
         connection.zAdd(cacheUpdate[0], cacheUpdate[1], cacheUpdate[2]);
     connection.exec()
      return null
   }
}, true);
```

The code works fine when `cacheList` is small, but we're trying to load about 1M small objects, and that creates the timeout issue..

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:46)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:90)
        at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.fill(RedisInputStream.java:110)
        at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:46)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:59)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:122)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getAll(Connection.java:207)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryTransaction.exec(BinaryTransaction.java:25)
        at com.oppen.fund.FundService$1.doInRedis(FundService.groovy:397)
```

We set the timeout in the Redis config to -1, but Redis does not seem to honor it, I'm assuming -1 means no timeout?

```
cacheLoaderJedisConnectionFactory(JedisConnectionFactory) {      
   hostName = '${grails.cache.redis.hostName}'
   port = '${grails.cache.redis.port}'
   timeout = -1
   password = null
   poolConfig = ref('grailsCacheJedisPoolConfig')       
}
```

We tried this both on WebLogic 11 and Tomcat 7, same timeout issue.

Answer (score 0):

**

### UPDATE

**

After further investigation, using `-1` for the Redis cache connection timeout was the issue; we used a very large positive value instead, eliminating the timeout problem.